# Is there a SYSTEM enumerator that already exists to indicate text character casing?

Tags: vb.net, enums

```
Function CaseCompress(str As String, Optional strCase As String = "lower") As String
    Select Case strCase
        Case "lower"
            Return New String(str.ToLower.ToCharArray().Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())
        Case "upper"
            Return New String(str.ToUpper.ToCharArray().Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())
        Case Else
            Return New String(str.ToCharArray().Where(Function(c) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())
    End Select
End Function
```

Briefly, the above function simply removes all whitespace and standardizes text case. I use it primarily for text-fingerprinting comparison (my description). :-) I want to "dress-up" the function, that is I want to make the optional choice a more-standardized choice hopefully using an enumerator instead of a "string" choice -- like this:

```
Function CaseCompress(str As String, Optional strCase As TextCase = TextCase.Lower) As String
```

I realize that I *may* have to remove the CaseElse but I'll deal with that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.text.capstyle(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Habib I saw this but can't see how to implement it... can you?

Comment: I am not sure if you can use it somehow to convert string to specific case, I would rather stick with what you have currently

Comment: CapStyle is from WPF assemblies, so you need to reference the WPF assemblies if you are working in WinForms, not a proper solution, if you just want to have a 'String-casing' enumeration, then create it. Is not clear for me what you want, but maybe could check my API for ideas: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.5/Elektro.Core/Text/Extensions/String/Rename.vb and https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.5/Elektro.Core/Text/Enums/StringCase.vb

Comment: @ElektroStudios -- Yes, I just figured that out -- thanks, though for pointing that out. It would be WAY overkill. I think that I may just have to roll my own -- I just thought for sure something already existed...

Comment: I totally understand you in that point of view, I also like to use built-in members, even for simple enums, instead of reinventing the wheel. I didn't remember if exist a similar enum for string casing, sorry.

Comment: Nice job on your Enums in your API. We think alike. Very well laid out. :-)